# BizTalk Message Tracking not working

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

We have a new BizTalk instance set up, and have Message Tracking enabled on some events. The Tracked Message Events appear in the query, but trying to open the details results in this error message:

> The message was not found in the Message Box or the Tracking
>   databases. This may be caused by one of the following conditions: (1)
>   message tracking is not enabled; (2) the message(s) is no longer
>   referenced by a running or suspended service instance; (3) the Message
>   Box tracking tables have been automatically purged; or (4) the SQL
>   Server agent is not running on the Message Box servers.
>   (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)

Going through this list:

1. Message Tracking is enabled at the Host level and at the Group level
2. Message body tracking is enabled, which MSDN says will keep the message beyond the lifetime of the instance
3. The Purge job for the Message Tracking tables is disabled
4. SQL Server Agent is running

What else could be going wrong or are we missing?

Answer (score 2):

You stated that message tracking is turned on for a host. Verify that a corresponding host instance is enabled.

In addition to verifying that the SQL Server Agent is running, you should ensure that the SQL job for "TrackedMessages_Copy_BizTalkMsgBoxDb" is enabled and running successfully.

Comment: Yes, and yes. The host instance is running, the job runs successfully every minute; and the tracked message events appear in query results, but the messages themselves are gone.